# How to read response from redirected POST url to our project from payment gateway in angular 7?

Tags: angular

My URL is redirected by payment gateway by post method, how can i read response from redirected post URL?

i m getting error `"Cannot POST /"`

[image]

I have tried below but didn't worked.

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: any) => {
  console.log(params);
})
```

Comment: Feel free to provide stackblitz example which Will be helpful to reproduce an issue

Comment: actually I m using Paytm payment gateway and my payment succeed and they are redirecting to my url as POST method... what i need to provide in stackblitz?

Comment: Can you show that api call code??

Comment: using this Form Submission
 "<form method="post" action="https://securegw- 
stage.paytm.in/order/process" name="paytm" #paytmForm >
...
</form>"

Comment: Why don't you use HTTPClient to call an API??

Comment: that won't worked... they provided HTML Form Post only... you can check this link    
https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/payment-gateway/

Comment: Then you have to read there document

Comment: but they are POST redirecting to my page not simply redirecting... thats why page not responding and they given jquery based documentation...